# using butterworth filter in a case structure

Tags: signal-processing, labview

I'm trying to use butterworth filter. The input data comes from an "index array" module (the data is acquired through DAQ and I want to process the voltage signal which is in an array of waveforms). when I use this filter in a case structure, it doesn't work. yet, when I use the filters in the "waveform conditioning" section, there is no problem. what exactly is the difference between these two types of filters?

[image]

[image]

a little add on to my problem: the second picture is from when i tried to reassemble the initial combination, and the error happened

Comment: Could you add a link to a snippet of your code? Somebody else will update your question to include the code.

Comment: My problem has changed a little, I have added 2 picture to the question. see if that helps in anyway. please tell me if you want any other details.I'll be as clear as possible. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing offline filtering to online filtering.
In LabVIEW, the PtbyPt-VIs are intended to be used in an online setting, that is - iteratively.
For each new sample that is obtained, it would be input directly into the VI. The VI stores the states of the previous iterations to perform the filtering.

The "normal" filter VIs are intended for offline analysis and expects an array containing the full data of the signal.

The following whitepaper explains Point-by-Point-VIs. Note that this paper is quite old, so it should explain the concepts - but might be otherwise outdated.
http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/370152b.pdf

Comment: I have set the sampling rate on 1000 for both the filter and the input, and the low cutoff frequency is set, so I'm not sure if that's the problem. yet i'm facing this new problem that says there is a mismatch between the type of the input and that of the filter. specifically it says "the type of the source is single and the type of the sink is 1D array of double". I even tried using conversion  to double, but it didn't work. the problem is at first there was no such error(i just figured i have to wait for validation of my pictures,sorry for the trouble)

Answer (score 0):

If *VoltageBuf* is an array of consecutive values of the same signal (the one that you want to filter) you only need to connect *VoltageBuf* directly to the filter.